# Do Cloudfront Redirects from http to https keep the request headers

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, reverse-proxy, amazon-cloudfront

Do Cloudfront Redirects from http to https keep the request headers. I can see that a 301 is returned, but are the headers such as authorization forwarded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is up to the browser, or other HTTP client application, to send a new request to the location indicated in the 301 response from CloudFront. Web browsers should re-issue the entire request, including all headers, to the new address.